# Django Images in row view

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have created a model in Django where I can upload the picture in the admin site and later it will be displayed in the homepage.

*.html file

```
<!-- templates/home.html -->
<h1>Django Image Uploading</h1>
<ul>
  {% for post in object_list %}
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <img src="{{ post.cover.url}}" alt="{{ post.title }}">
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

How can I display all pictures in a row view ? instead of column ? (image-gallery kind of page I wanted to built)

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned bootstrap-4 as one of the tags, here is the way to do so using bootstrap;

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> <!-- all the divs placed inside this div will be placed in a row instead of column -->
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All the `divs`inside the `div` with class `row` will be placed horisontally in a row.

For more click here; https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#row-columns

Comment: Don't forget to get the Bootstrap in your project either by downloading or by getting the CDN